# How can I incorporate my return method with this snippet of code? (Java, Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, function, class, return

How would I go about getting the return value from this piece of code?
It doesn't let me use the return function within my FOR loop, and I don't know how to proceed.

It should return an object stored in the Array List al (which was declared in my main method) but I am unable to get the method to correctly return the Student object.

Any tips?

```
public static Student getStudentByNumber(int number1, ArrayList<Student> al)
{
    for(Iterator<Student> it = al.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
    {
        if(number1 == it.next().getStudentNumber())
        {

            return it.next();       
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Just declare a dummy `Student` before you enter the loop. `return` the student instead

Comment: @Hendais you are not returning the student with studentNumber == to number1 you are returning the next student in the list after the student with studentNumber == number1...

Comment: Since you're obviously a student yourself - doesn't your teacher teach you how to test?! (This is a rant not about you but about your teacher or book) I would first teach students how to test, then how to write such functions.

Comment: We've kind of touched on the debugger and whatnot, but I am still struggling a little when it comes to somewhat more complex methods and their implementation. I only started coding once I started uni 2 months ago, so I am still kinda new to the whole thing too.

Comment: The debugger is a misnomer. The debugger should be called livetracer. The debugger does not debug - it does not remove bugs. If you have code you don't understand no matter how hard you look at it, the debugger can be a great tool to step through the code in order to get a better understanding. Debugging in order to remove errors is a stupid waste of time. The proper way to find errors, or rather prevent (most) of them from sneaking in in the first place, is unit testing and *Test Driven Development*. Ask your teacher about that and Google it up. Especially: **Debugging != Testing** :)

Comment: I will definitely check it out, thank you very much :)

However, I tried your code, and this was the only output I got: 

practicalSessions_24_11_2014.Student@15db9742

Am I doing something wrongly?

Comment: @Hendais I think you're doing everything right, and whatever is printed and you call "the only output" is not directly related to this code. You have a new problem, you should analyze and and try to fix it. If you don't succeed, post a new question, describing your problem (what is expected behavior, what is actual behavior), what you've tried and what you've found out.

Comment: Thanks! I realised what I was doing wrongly, and I got it sorted :)

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the `return` inside the `for`, but that there is no `return` outside the `for`. Think about what happens if `al.isEmpty()`. And think about how often you actually loop. Rethink the placement of the `return null`.

Consider that invoking `it.next()` a second time is probably not intended - were you really returning the correct element? What if it were the last student that matched?

*Be careful about names*. It's better to name variables regarding what they mean than what they are. And be consistent.

The `ArrayList` / `Collection` contains Students, and that's how it should be named: `students`.

If a `Student` could have another number besides the `studentNumber`, i.e. SSN, we should be more precise about number whenever we mention it. In that case, `getStudentByNumber` should be renamed to `getStudentByStudentNumber` and `number` should be renamed to `studentNumber`. If the `studentNumber` is the only number that a `Student` has, it should be renamed to `number`, because in that case `Student.studentNumber` would be redundant, i.e. `Student.getStudentNumber()` should be renamed to `Student.getNumber()`.

*Types should always be as specific as required, but no more specific.* In other words: *Types should be as generic as possible.* If your method takes `ArrayList`, it only works with `ArrayList`. If your method takes `List`, it takes all types of lists, like `ArrayList` as well as `LinkedList`. If your method takes `Collection`, it works with even more types. And there is no reason why it should work with `ArrayList` only. So the type actually should be `Collection`.

But anyhow, Java is much simpler than that. Instead of using an `Iterator` explicitly, you can let Java do the work for you.

```
public static Student getStudentByNumber(int number, Collection<Student> students) {
    for (Student student : students) {
        if (student.getStudentNumber() == number) {
            return student;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I would consider swapping the order of the parameters. It is more logical / convention, to first specify where to search, and then what to search, like this:

```
public static Student getStudentByNumber(Collection<Student> students, int number) {
    for (Student student : students) {
        if (student.getStudentNumber() == number) {
            return student;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And with *Functional Programming* in Java it gets even simpler:

```
public static Student getStudentByNumber(Collection<Student> students, int number) {
    return students.stream()
        .filter(student -> student.getStudentNumber() == number)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: I'll +1 if you add braces to both statements.

Comment: Hehe, good one. I would rather extract methods instead of adding braces.

Comment: I changed my mind. Maybe it's better to put braces as long as "Extract 'till you drop" is not yet known to everybody.

Comment: When I try out this code, the only output I get to the console after having passed the correct parameters into the method and having printed it is this: practicalSessions_24_11_2014.Student@15db9742

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you're doing everything right, and whatever is printed is not directly related to this code, means should be in a new question - but first try and read yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It's cleaner if you declare a variable to hold your eventual return value, regardless of what that variable will hold eventually:

```
public static Student getStudentByNumber(int number1, ArrayList<Student> al)
{
   Student studentToReturn = null  //return value variable
    for(Iterator<Student> it = al.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
    {
        studentToReturn = it.next();
        if(number1 == studentToReturn.getStudentNumber() )
        {

           return studentToReturn;

        }

         //get rid of the unnecessary if
    }

return studenToReturn; 

}
```

Comment: Make sure you understand this will not return the student with student number1 it will return the next student after that...

Comment: I strongly disagree.  Temporary variables like these clutter the code and make it harder to find real problems; they're founded on the obsolete notion that "a method should have exactly one return point".  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement

Comment: Well, that's all well and good @CarlManaster. I'm not an adherent to "that obsolete notion"; I just find it more convenient for me. It's a matter of style, not right or wrong.